# Should the Angular Application use ngModules concept or pages when dividing into view routes?

Tags: angular

I'm thinking about how to divide my Angular(5) project structure properly and optimally. There is a concept of dividing the structure into specific ngModules but the aim can be also achievied via using components as e.g. VIEWS / PAGES.

What is the best approach when having below business structure? Which elements should be understood as modules and which as pages / views / components belonging to those modules ?

Should I think about modules at all?

PS. Most of those presented views contains tables (1 or 2 tables per view) + forms.

```
.
├── HOME
├── MONITOR
|   ├── MONITOR subpage 1 (table)
|   └── MONITOR subpage 2 (table)
├── SCHEDULE
|   ├── SCHEDULE subpage 1 (table)
|   └── SCHEDULE subpage 2 (form)
├── DATA ANALYSIS
|   ├── DATA ANALYSIS subpage 1 (2 tables)
|   └── DATA ANALYSIS subpage 2 (table)
├── DATA QUALITY
|   ├── DATA QUALITY subpage 1 (form)
|   └── DATA QUALITY subpage 2 (table)
├── CONFIGURATION 
└── USER SETUP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you got the roles of Angular correctly.

(Or I didn't get your question correctly)

Anyway, in both cases, let me explain it thoroughly.

#### Modules

Angular modules are features that allow to define how a given part of your application will work.

In a module, you define the components, you import the dependencies, and you export the features you want to use in other modules.

#### Components

Angular components are a feature that allow you to put logic into your views. A component is made of a class, and a template. They are declared into a module, and are used to display something to the user (and handle user interactions).

### Structure

There is no rule about a project structure, only good practice. No-one will blame you for not following them.

[According to the style guide](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide), your structure should be LIFT :

- **L**ocate easily your files
- **I**dentify the purpose of a file easily
- **F**latten your structure by having maximum 7 files per folder
- **T**ry to **D**on't **R**epeat **Y**ourself.

If I were you, in the case of your structure, I would do this

```
.
├── Home (module)
├── Monitor (module, component with router-outlet)
|   ├── Monitor page 1 (component)
|   └── Monitor page 2 (component)
// Same for the others, I'm DRY
└── User setup (module, service)
```